# UID might be blank?

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm using Firebase for keeping track of user's subscription information. They have to register in Firebase and then, after their purchase completed, Firebase will setup/renew their subscription. The database is structured

```
root
 -> users
   -> UID
     ->user info
```

I add new user info like this:

```
func setExpiration() {
    guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
        return
    }

    let usersRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users")

    usersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (dataSnapshot) in
        if let dict = dataSnapshot.value as? [String : [String : String]] {
            ...

            // Checks to see if the user exists in the database yet.
            if let userDict = dict[user.uid] {
                ...

                usersRef.child(user.uid).updateChildValues(keyedValues, withCompletionBlock: { (error, databaseReference) in
                    if let error = error {
                        ...

                        return
                    }

                    ...
                })
                // User does not exist in database and needs added.
            } else {
                ...

                usersRef.updateChildValues([user.uid : keyedValues], withCompletionBlock: { (error, databaseReference) in
                    if let error = error {
                        ...

                        return
                    }

                    ...
                })
            }
        }
    })
}
```

My problem is that sometimes lately, the user info goes straight in the `users` bucket instead of in their UID. After playing around with this I cannot replicate the issue. So far it seems not all of our users have this problem. Is it possible that the uid might be coming back blank at times and that's causing it to write to the wrong place?

Comment: All we can say with the code you provided is that `user.uid` seems undefined in that case. To allow us to best help you, look into [creating a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the reply. I did test it out with a blank string and it gave me an error that it can't have empty keys. I've updated my post like you requested.